# I want to get a value from a textbox and put it in the i in a for loop

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to get a value from a textbox in html and give it to the i in the for loop but my program does not works:

var k = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

```
for (var i = k; i < n; i+=4) {
    //for (var j = 0; j < n; j+=4) {
    pixelComponents[i ] = pixelComponents[i ] + 100; //red
    pixelComponents[i+1] = pixelComponents[i+1]+0;       //green
    pixelComponents[i+2] = pixelComponents[i+2]+0;    //blue
    //}
}
```

Also I tried this and it doesn't work too:

```
for (var i = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;; i < n; i+=4) {
    //for (var j = 0; j < n; j+=4) {
    pixelComponents[i ] = pixelComponents[i ] + 100; //red
    pixelComponents[i+1] = pixelComponents[i+1]+0;       //green
    pixelComponents[i+2] = pixelComponents[i+2]+0;    //blue
    //}
}
```

Comment: wwhat is n here i < n

Answer (score 2):

The value of a textbox is a string. Try doing:

```
var k = parseInt(document.getElementById("textbox1").value, 10);
```

Interestingly, in javascript doing ++ on a string converts it to a number, but doing += 4 appends the character 4:

```
var x = "1"; console.log(++x);
2 

var x = "1"; console.log((x += 4));
14
```

Note that even if you set the value of a textbox to be a number, when you retrieve it it is once again a string:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("someTextBox");
textBox.value = 8;
alert(textBox.value + 4); // 84, not 12
```

Comment: it is not a string i thing:                                                                 <input name="textbox1" id="textbox1" type="text" onKeyUp="numericFilter(this);" />

Comment: Also the double semi-colon is likely to cause problems.